# Laravel application switched to prepared statements

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, prepared-statement, sql-server-2016

I have an application, custom written by a an external company, in PHP/Laravel.
In latest version, there were the following changes:

- PHP version changed to v7.3.6
- Laravel changed from v5.2 to v5.7
- Changed all SQL to use prepared statements

Since the release, users are upset because pages take much longer to load. I found out that this is caused by SQL prepared statements: while previously I had 20-30 few queries per day taking more than 3 seconds, up to a maximum of 10-20 seconds, now I have ten times more, and single queries may take 1-2 minutes.
I understand that this is good to prevent SQL injections etc, but the result is unacceptable.

From what I see, the application always prepares statement, uses it once and dumps it: there is no reuse.

Would it be possible, by making some simple change in code, to at least try what would happens by switching all queries to regular queries, without modifying any single place in the code that builds a query?

I installed SP2 and CU8 on my SQL Server, as I know this prevents some issues with prepared statements.

Comment: I dont think prepared queries will have that much of a speed impact, its more likely that the queries themselves are inefficient, or that the data is not correctly indexed.

Comment: When the new version was released, I have not done changes to the indexes.
Maybe the prepared statements need different indexes?

Comment: I don't know the real effects or downsides, but seen that you can pass PDO options in the connection configuration, this seems on topic: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true` https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php The laravel default is `false` in Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php

Comment: Install something like Tracy Debug Bar which will show you how many queries you're doing, where in the code it's coming from. Check that you are reusing queries as much as possible, that you're lazy loading. Swap out function queries for joins, that helps with speed. Index your data!

Comment: I assume that problem is in eloquent or database queries. Laravel works with collections and probably some pages or apis query too big collections. You should review your request instead.

Comment: I can see exactly which queries are executed.
Important to note: the code was running fine, the queries were acceptable, until there was the switch in PHP/Laravel versions, and application started using prepared statements.